# OutputCache Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client doesnt work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, outputcache

I am attempting to use `OutputCache` for caching of images (returned from a DB).  Unfortunately this doesnt seem to work.  If I set `Location = OutputCacheLocation.ServerAndClient` it caches it correctly on the server, but never the browser?  Any suggestions as to why?

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, 
            VaryByParam = "serialNumber;activityId", 
            Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client, 
            NoStore = true)]
public ActionResult GetImage(string serialNumber, int activityId)
{
    var byteArray = this.service.GetImage(serialNumber, activityId);
    return File(byteArray, "image/jpeg"); // adjust content type appropriately
}
```

Comment: have you found out why? i am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you set **NoStore** to true? I think it should work if you remove:

```
NoStore = true
```